# creating multilevel array using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-2

I have two table whose structure is as

## Table Circle_member

```
->user_id
->circle_id
```

## Table User

```
->user_id
->username
```

What I trying to get is 
i first want to send circle id to the circle_model to get the id of all users in the array till this m fine. But now by using the same model can i generate multi level array which contains users informations too like as:

## MODEL

```
public function get_circle_members($circle_id){
        $result = $this->db->select('*');
        $result = $this->db->from(TBL_USER_PROFILE. ' as p');

        $result = $this->db->join(TBL_MEMBER. ' as m', 'p.user_id = m.user_id');
       // $result = $this->db->where('m.circle_id', $circle_id);
        //$result = $this->db->where('m.user_id', $circle_id);            
        $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result;


["id":1
    {
      "username":"yubraj",
      "user_id":1,
    }
]
```

Comment: Show your code of model

Comment: i have updated my question avove hope this will help

Comment: What is output of `print_r($result)`?

Comment: CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #48 [result_id] => Resource id #70 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 2 [row_data] => )

Comment: You should return `$result->fetch_array()` or try `print_r($result->fetch_array())` to see result data. $result is **result_object** not result data.

Comment: thank you bro thats silly mistake i had made any way thanks u bro

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you don't need to have a multi level array in this situation since you will have one level of data since one user ID will link to only one user account.

```
[
    {
     "id":1,
      "username":"yubraj",
      "user_id":1,
    },
    {
     "id":2,
      "username":"yubraj",
      "user_id":1,
    }
]
```

And your model function will be something like this.

```
public function get_circle_members($circle_id){
    $result = $this->db->select('*');
    $result = $this->db->from(TBL_USER_PROFILE. ' as p');
    $result = $this->db->join(TBL_MEMBER. ' as m', 'p.user_id = m.user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```